# VBA retrieve errors found in running query with DoCmd.RunQuery

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm running a bunch of MS-Access querys from a VBA script using DoCmd.RunQuery, some of this querys when runned directly give errors of the kind "MS Access could not add XX registers due to ... " and I would like to get a log of them.

Something like

```
DoCmd.RunQUery "query 1"
If "There is an Error" Then
    Debug.Print "error message"
End If
```

And I would like to know how I can implement "There is an error" and "error message" parts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
CurrentDb.Execute "sql query", dbFailOnError
lngErrNum = Err.Number
strErrDescr = Err.Description
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
If lngErrNum <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print strErrDescr
End If
```